# Handsontable Hooks undefined or null when trying to create table IE10

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-10, handsontable

I will start with the browser that I am using is IE 10, well that I have to support.
I am walking through the start guide and when creating the grid I get a property error, specifically that `Unable to get property 'hooks' of undefined or null reference`. It runs fine on 11, Chrome, Firefox and Edge.

Has anyone had this issue or know what I may be doing wrong?

Tutorial: https://handsontable.com/docs/6.2.0/tutorial-quick-start.html

Compatibility: https://handsontable.com/docs/6.2.0/tutorial-compatibility.html

Snippet:

```js
var data = [
  ["", "Ford", "Tesla", "Toyota", "Honda"],
  ["2017", 10, 11, 12, 13],
  ["2018", 20, 11, 14, 13],
  ["2019", 30, 15, 12, 13]
];

var div = document.getElementById('grid');
var hot = new Handsontable(div, {
  data: data,
  rowHeaders: true,
  colHeaders: true,
  filters: true,
  dropdownMenu: true
});
```

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

I've referred to the tutorial and made a sample on my side. The result works well on IE10. Here is my testing code.

```
<body>
<div id="grid"></div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/handsontable-pro@6.2.0/dist/handsontable.full.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/handsontable-pro@6.2.0/dist/handsontable.full.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<script>
    var data = [
        ["", "Ford", "Tesla", "Toyota", "Honda"],
        ["2017", 10, 11, 12, 13],
        ["2018", 20, 11, 14, 13],
        ["2019", 30, 15, 12, 13]
    ];

    var div = document.getElementById('grid');
    var hot = new Handsontable(div, {
        data: data,
        rowHeaders: true,
        colHeaders: true,
        filters: true,
        dropdownMenu: true
    });
</script>
</body>
```

[image: the runing resulut]

I wonder that if you've followed the tutorial step by step. Both npm install handsontable-pro and embed the reference link are necessary. Or if you have added extra codes which have affected the result.

Comment: I should make an edit then. I am using the CE and emulation of IE10 (document mode) from IE11. @JeniferJiang

Comment: Hello,I've tried to edit in the table but it seems to be no error from the browser. You could see from the capture:https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GBXp.gif